# Debugging a web service method

Tags: web-services, debugging, proxy

I have a web service URL with me. This web service is deployed in a server. I need to test a single method in this web service.
What all are the steps to be done for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is your application server..? Which language you have implemented in your service? Usually most of the application servers support remote debugging... If it is java you need to start your application server in debug mode and can attach your code through remote debugging either using Eclipse or any other IDE. If you are using .NET then through Visual Studio - you can attach the code to the running process.

Comment: Its a .net windows app. The web service I'm accessing is a web service provided by Microsoft CCF framework, which means I dont have that service code :(
Is it possible to create a proxy object for this service, and access thru that proxy?
I actually tried it, and added a client side configuration file for the web service, but when I try to access the service method thru the proxy, it says "Object Reference not set"
Am i missing somehting?

Comment: If you want to debug the service, you need to have the service code with you. You can create a service reference to your service and call it via a client - but still won't be able to debug the service.

Comment: Ok. For the time-being I think I just need to check the service method result, without stepping/debugging into the service method. In that case, what will be the problem with my proxy object? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to invoke a web-service an view the result, you could simply use SoapUi

- You have  to download it :
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/4.0/
- Create a new project and give the WSDL URL of your service (the WSDL could be retrieve by adding '?WSDL' to the URL)
- A sample request for each operation have been generated, just replace the '?' by sample value in the request and run

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use the soap UI.

The other method is to generate the client stub with some tool (eg. with Axis2 you can use wsdl2java tool) and invoke the service. Again this can be done through tcpmon in order to see the request and response messages.